# GNU Radio - How to send PMT string type to debug block in Python Block

Tags: gnuradio

I'm attempting to send a Python string, basically for debug purposes, from a GNU Radio Python Block to a Message Debug block. Whilst I can do this easily for an integer using a PMT pair, I can't figure out how to send a simple string. I've gone over the documentation of course, but I'm having trouble interpreting in. There is no simple complete example I can find.

I've edited this question eliminating my non-functional code which was probably not helpful.

So let's say I have a debug port set up in the **INIT** section of a Python Block as follows

```
        self.portName1 = "debugOutput"
        self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern(self.portName1))
```

and I have a Python string variable in the "work" function

```
        test_str = "This is a test"
```

what code do I need to send this string to the Debug Block?

Comment: `PMT_debug_msg = pmt.string.to.symbol(cfg_str)` that's not even close to correct usage of Python. Please make sure you're actually using the functionality as it exists, not something incorrectly copied! Voting to close as caused by a typo / copy and paste error.

Comment: Well, I know it's wrong or I wouldn't have asked for help !

Comment: But the problem is: we don't know where you came up with the idea to make it such! It's not natural to me to try and use the functionality that doesn't exist, so I have to assume you copied it from somewhere – which is very fine! But then you must have made a copying mistake, and its easier for you to fix that than it is for us.

Comment: Well, I didn't copy it from anywhere, It's just my attempt to make it work. I am failing to understand the correct method of sending a string type to a Debug Python bug. I'll rephrase the question eliminating the non functional code since it's obviously nowhere near correct.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently a bit short on time, but this question did pop up on the GNU Radio chat server's "monitor Stackoverflow" room, so chances are someone else might pop by :)